# ENTER key in excel userform executes a command button's Click event

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

The ENTER key pressed anywhere on the userform executes a command button's Click event. I do not understand why and I do not want this to happen.
I have copied all the controls to a new workbook without any code behind it and it still does it so the problem would not be in any code.
When I delete the control that ENTER executes the Click event of, the Click event of another control get triggered.
How can I stop this?
Your ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: When you load a Userform, chances are that there are for example commandbuttons on that userform. There is (in my experiece) always an element active/selected. Pressing enter would trigger the corresponding `Click_event` to trigger. I can't replicate the behaviour when you remove the `Click_event` code on the active element to trigger other click events to happen on pressing enter. Is there some `Application.OnKey` behaviour going on?

Comment: Application.OnKey would be in the code right? I copied all the controls to a new workbook without any code and it still does it.
I am about to recreate the whole form from scratch, see if it works and then copy the code into it.
It doesn't feel right.

Comment: I just selected the cmdButton it sets focus to and set it to .enabled=False.
That seems to work, in the sense that the form behaves as expected but it still gives me an uneasy feeling, leaving that in a finished deliverable product.

Comment: The onkey can be set on userform initialize or even in any macro, for example when workbook opens. But I doubt that would be the case.